# Gridster equivalent grid plugin

Tags: angularjs, gridster

I am looking for a gridster.net like plugin that work well with angularJS. Gridster.net was excellent but it's not responsive.

Following are the features I am looking in the grid.

- Responsive
- Drag and drop
- Re-size
- Serialize and rebuild the grid from serialized data (gridster has this feature)
- Dynamically access, create and re-size grid cells

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [this review of jquery grid plugins](http://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/2014/09/comparing-jquery-grid-plugins-masonry-vs-isotope-vs-packery-vs-gridster-vs-shapeshift-vs-shuffle-js/)? Then you can search for the equivalent Angular module...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I looked into it. I analyzed packery and Shapeshift from the list. Packery had limitations with resize and serialize the grid(or I didn't find the options for this from their documentation). Phaseshit was depend up on another plug-in for drag and drop feature. I I had to drop both.